# How do you automatically delete screenshot?

Tags: iphone, ios, screen-capture

A common workflow for me is to take a screenshot of something on my iPhone, click on the floating thumbnail, click share to send it to someone... and now I want the screenshot deleted and I want to return to where I was as fast as possible.

What's the fastest way out that makes sure the screenshot is deleted? For example, can I change a setting so that tapping "done" deletes the screenshot and exits?

Answer (score 1):

- create screenshot
- tap on "Done" on top left
- select "Copy and delete"
- open app you want to use for sharing and paste

Comment: I would like that to be the default action, I would prefer not to have to click twice every time. It's especially annoying because there are two options that look identical, so you have to slow down every time to actually read everything in the Close actions list

Comment: There's a Trash icon in the upper right.

Comment: @theonlygusti The menu entries are always at the same place, should become a habit after 5 or 10 times.

Comment: @MarcWilson that still asks for confirmation